# How to update data in database with the same ID?

Tags: mysql

I have a table, where user stores it's preferences by checkboxes. First insert works fine, but what if the user wants to update the preferences? My current logic will create new rows which is bad.

Somebody told me to delete all the rows associated with the user and then reinsert, but I read that it will put a lot of load on the server.

Another would be serialize, but I heard that it is a bad practice.

How can I update only the preference that user wants to change? (lets say user unchecks the age 0-1 and checks 7-10. Then it should delete 0-1 from database, and add 7-10.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2 img-thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/images/boy_icon.png" alt="pencil" class="img-circle">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" data-id="1" name="childAgeRanges[]" value="0-1" checked="checked">
                <label for="0-1">age 0-1</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 img-thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/images/boy_icon.png" alt="pencil" class="img-circle">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" data-id="2" id="1-3" name="childAgeRanges[]" value="1-3" checked="checked">
                <label for="1-3">age1-3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 img-thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/images/boy_icon.png" alt="pencil" class="img-circle">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" data-id="3" id="4-6" name="childAgeRanges[]" value="4-6" checked="checked">
                <label for="4-6">age 4-6</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 img-thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/images/boy_icon.png" alt="pencil" class="img-circle">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="7-10" name="childAgeRanges[]" value="7-10" checked="checked">
                <label for="7-10">age 7-10</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My table:

```
age_id | user_id        | range_id
1        1              | 0-1
2        1              | 1-3
3        1              | 4-6
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the `UPDATE` keyword?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: @David no, because if I do update where user_id = 1 then it will update all of the values that have user_id 1.

Comment: So you're *not* looking to update the data?  I guess I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do then.

Comment: @David update is what I am looking for. What I am trying to do is: how can I update the specific row? so lets say user unchecks the 0-1 and checks 7-10. Then in database it should delete the row 0-1 and add a new row with a value 7-10. Right now  if I do what I explained you, it will add just a new row but if I uncheck the 0-1 it will not remove it from database.

Comment: `update table set range_id={whatever} where user_id={userid} and age_id={ageid}` ?

Comment: @Jakumi how do I get the age_id to the checkbox because the checkboxes are pre defined  ?

Comment: well, how do you get user_id ? are you using ajax, html forms, ... ? more actual program code would help to answer your question.

Comment: @raqulka: What you're describing sounds more like deleting rows and adding new rows, not really updating anything.  So when the user posts the form, delete the rows which exist in the DB but don't match what's in the form, and add the rows which exist in the form but not in the DB.  What have you actually tried?  The question contains no code which interacts with a DB at all.

Answer (score 0):

For this example before running update query select user age list. Loop them and check if they are in the childAgeRanges array. If not delete with its id. You can use same way to add them too. Loop childAgeRanges array and check if they are in the resultset. But if you ask me i would definitely delete all ages then add them again. Ot would use much less resource on server and code wont be a mess. And beleive me removing and adding will not effect your server that badly and users usually dont make these types of changes so much in their settings.